# Bicycle rental in Belo Horizonte?

Tags: bicycles, brazil

I want to rent a bicycle in Belo Horizonte, in Brazil.

The [default bike sharing scheme](http://www.movesamba.com.br/bikebh/home.asp) is only available in a limited area and has the main issue that you can only rent bikes for one hour at a time (1.5 on Sundays). Additionally, the same bike sharing scheme in other Brazilian cities has degraded significantly in recent years, meaning I'm not too hopeful about this one.

[BikeMania](https://www.facebook.com/aluguel.bikemania/) no longer operates a website. They have two branches, both close to Pampulha, which is where I want to go for a ride, but a downtown location would be more practical.
They charge R$10,00, R$20,00 (with gears) and R$30,00 ('triciclo família') per hour, which means they expect you to rent for an hour or two, not for a day.

[SpaceJoy](https://www.facebook.com/www.spacejoy.com.br/) (thanks @Dorothy), also close to Pampulha, charges R$10 per hour for 'basic' bikes.

Where to rent a bicycle in BH?

Comment: Asking in chat on [bicycles.se] might also be a good option. (Note to trigger-happy close voters: that doesn't mean the question is off-topic, here!)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two alternatives, both businesses on Facebook

[Spacejoy](https://www.facebook.com/www.spacejoy.com.br/) is a bicycle rental shop in Belo Horizonte, near the Fox's Lair and the Pampulha Ecological Park at the edge of the lake (próximo a toca da raposa e o parque ecológico na orla da lagoa da Pampulha).
Avenida Otacílio Negrão de Lima 6696
Belo Horizonte, MG 31365450
+55 31 3140-7940
https://www.facebook.com/www.spacejoy.com.br/

[Zoobiker](https://www.facebook.com/zoobiker/) is an enthusiasts' group, not a bike rental, but may be able to connect you to what's available in the area.
+55 31 99975-9975
https://www.facebook.com/zoobiker

Comment: Thanks. It's saddening that Spacejoy also no longer maintains a website. I had found Zoobiker as well (who, incidentally, also no longer operate a website). I'll give them a shout.

Comment: @MastaBaba and do come back and answer your own question, or edit mine, after your return. Boa viagem.